# Setting the property of one specific key in an object in a reduce is setting it for all properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay, I have literally no idea whats going on here. I'm assuming its some kind of reference issue? But I dont know how to get around it or whats causing it.

To sum it up, I have a list of objects, as well as an object that gets prepopulated to make sure I have data for all keys in the object.

I need to iterate over this list of objects, and by using the timeframeId in the metadata object, and the id in the data object, I want to assign the entire data object to the corresponding timeframeId and id hierarchy in the prepopulated object.

For some reason, all `data` properties are being overwritten to whatever the last row `data` is.

I've linked a repl so you can see for yourself: https://repl.it/@ThomasVermeers1/UnwrittenNoisyFirm#index.js

But my code is as follows:

```
const buildSegmentsFromRows = (rows, timeframeMetadata, defaultSegmentData) => {
  // Prepopulate object to make sure every timeframe has a 'hello' key in it with some data
  const emptySegments = timeframeMetadata.reduce((segmentMap, metadata) => {
    segmentMap[metadata.timeframeId] = {
      metadata,
      segments: defaultSegmentData,
    };
    return segmentMap;
  }, {});

  // Now simply just loop over the rows, and set [row.metadata.timeframeId].segments[row.data.id] to row.data
  const segments = rows.reduce((partialSegments, row) => {
    const { timeframeId } = row.metadata;
    const { id } = row.data;

    /**
     * This is the line where everything goes wrong
     */
    partialSegments[timeframeId].segments[id] = row.data;
    return partialSegments;
  }, emptySegments);
  return segments;
};

const rows = [
  {
    metadata: { timeframeId: '20202_01' },
    data: {
      'id': 'hello', 'value': 15
    }
  },
  {
    metadata: { timeframeId: '20202_02' },
    data: {
      'id': 'hello', 'value': 10
    }
  }
]

const timeframemetadata = [
  { timeframeId: '20202_01'},
  { timeframeId: '20202_02'}
]

const defaultSegmentData = {
  'hello': {
    'id': 'hello',
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(buildSegmentsFromRows(rows, timeframemetadata, defaultSegmentData), null, 2))
```

I'm expecting the end result to be:

```
{
  "20202_01": {
    "metadata": {
      "timeframeId": "20202_01"
    },
    "segments": {
      "hello": {
        "id": "hello",
        "value": 15
      }
    }
  },
  "20202_02": {
    "metadata": {
      "timeframeId": "20202_02"
    },
    "segments": {
      "hello": {
        "id": "hello",
        "value": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But instead, `value` is getting set to `10` in all instances. I'm thinking its because we're setting the property to `row.data`, which is a reference, and gets updated on every call? But I'm at a complete loss here.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if it's something to do w/ reference because if you even just replace `partialSegments[timeframeId].segments[id] = row.data;` to `partialSegments[timeframeId].segments[id] = Math.random();`

All values are set to the same random number.

Comment: You're probably attempting to reuse an object rather than create a whole new one somewhere in your code.  And, thus you end up with references to the same object all over your structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are referring to the same object for every `segments` in the list.

Therefore, changing the value of `segments[id]` will update `defaultSegmentData`, causing every reference to `defaultSegmentData` to change as well.

```js
  const emptySegments = timeframeMetadata.reduce((segmentMap, metadata) => {
    segmentMap[metadata.timeframeId] = {
      metadata,
      segments: defaultSegmentData, // Everything goes wrong here.
    };
    return segmentMap;
  }, {});
```

A simple solution to this problem is to avoid using the same reference to the object when creating the `segmentMap`:

```js
  const emptySegments = timeframeMetadata.reduce((segmentMap, metadata) => {
    segmentMap[metadata.timeframeId] = {
      metadata,
      /** Or whatever default value you want. 
      *   Just make sure to create a new instance of it for each call.
      */
      segments: {},
    };
    return segmentMap;
  }, {});
```

Comment: Yep this was definitely it. Thanks for the response! 
Just went with:
```
segments: {...defaultSegmentData },
```